# Widget with autoscroll text

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

I have widget which must show some text.
When text fits in widget - everything is fine.
But when text is longer, it should "autoscroll" - to left, and then back to right.
There are some devices which do exactly this - to show long song title or something alike.
I checked most of QT text components, but I do not see what I need.
Looks like, I have to make own component?

Comment: Yes, you have to make your own widget, although it can be very simple (a couple of lines).

Comment: It is a very specific behavior, so it would not be feasible for being handled by Qt proper, at least as of now. What is wrong about creating this logic on your side?

Comment: Thanks to all. I made own component - this was right decision - embedded hardware has some limitations. PS There is nothing wrong except: 
1. laziness :)
2. I am not very good with "Look and feel"